# Type of a function in SML

Tags: sml, currying

Can anyone explain to me why the type of the function given below is
`('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`?

The function is:

```
fun foldr f b [] = b 
  | foldr f b (x::xs) = f (x, (foldr f b xs))
```

When I look at this function, I find the type should just be `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b` since we have a function `f` which is taking in a tuple and just returning at `'b` and also in the base case we return the `'b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the type of a function, the process basically goes like this:

Given a function,

```
fun foldr f b []      = b
  | foldr f b (x::xs) = f (x, (foldr f b xs))
```

assume all types of the parameters and return value are unknown.

```
foldr   : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd
f (arg1): 'a
b (arg2): 'b
  (arg3): 'c
(return): 'd
```

---

```
fun foldr f b []      = b
```

First of all, we can see that `b` (arg2) is the same as the return type of `foldr` (return) and (arg3) is a list of some unknown type.

```
f (arg1): 'a
b (arg2): 'b
  (arg3): 'e list
(return): 'b
```

---

```
  | foldr f b (x::xs)
```

`x` and `xs` make up the list of (arg3).

```
f (arg1): 'a
b (arg2): 'b
  (arg3): 'e list
(return): 'b
x       : 'e
xs      : 'e list
```

---

```
                      = f (x, (foldr f b xs))
```

Then `f` (arg1) is a function that takes a 2-tuple and returns the same type as `foldr` returns (return).  The first item of the tuple is the same type of `x`.  The second item of the tuple is the same type of the return type of `foldr` (return).  The types also hold so far for the recursive call to `foldr`.

```
f (arg1): 'e * 'b -> 'b
b (arg2): 'b
  (arg3): 'e list
(return): 'b
x       : 'e
xs      : 'e list
```

---

```
fun foldr f b []      = b
  | foldr f b (x::xs) = f (x, (foldr f b xs))
```

It cannot be simplified any further so we have the type:

foldr: `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the above code for `foldr` is incorrect; it should be

```
fun  foldr f b [] = b 
   | foldr f b (x::xs) = (f x (foldr f b xs))
```

That is, it should not be passing in a tuple of arguments, but rather passing in the accumulator and the recursive call to `foldr` as arguments as usual.

As for where the type comes from, remember that `foldr` takes in three parameters:

1. The function to apply over the range.
2. The initial value of the accumulator.
3. The range over which to fold.

Let's say that the accumulator has type `'b` and that the list has type `'blist`.  We know that the overall return type of the function should be `'b`, because we have

```
fun  foldr f b [] = b
```

Let's now see what the type of `f` is.  We have this:

```
foldr f b (x::xs) = (f x (foldr f b xs))
```

This takes in the first element of the list and the accumulator, then produces something that must be of type `'b`.  The list has type `'a list` and the accumulator has type `'b`, so the function has type `('a * 'b -> 'b)`.

Summing this up, the type of the function is

```
('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

Which is what is being reported.

Comment: You are wrong about your version of `foldr`. It beats me how you can arrive at the correct conclusion of the type, when you write the `f` function to take its arguments curried. If still in doubt then you can check up with the [definition](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldr:VAL)

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg- I was under the impression that this question was about a custom foldr implementation, not the standard foldr implementation.  Is this incorrect?